# How to highlight the code

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

I have been read *[Javascript code prettifier](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)*, but I still didn't understand how to use prettify here on Stack Exchange sites... I can't copy highlighted text and I can reference the prettyfy function from this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta and the other SO family sites don't use the prettifier you linked to.  They use Markdown.  For more information on Markdown, you can click on the question mark in the colored block above and to the right of the answer or question submission fields.  Or, just click [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

If you're sure you wanted to ask about the JS code prettifier at Google Code, you probably meant to ask your question at [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/).  This site is Meta Stack Overflow, which is for questions about how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Erm, Markdown is used for message formatting, Prettify is used for code syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Balus, yeah... it was the only thing I could think of that was somewhat relevant, though.  It sure wouldn't be the first case of an SO user asking about one thing and meaning some other superficially similar thing.

Comment: Well, he explicitly asked "How to highlight the code" in the title and linked a crystal clear documentation of the right tool to do the job. I however don't disagree that this question is better to be asked on SO :) And preferably with more detail in the question since it's unclear at what step exactly he's stucking.

Comment: Thank you all for replay. I actually asked about how to highlight the code here on the forums. But I see that this done automatically.
Thank you again.